# Log an already executed query to a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL block:

```
begin
...
delete table1
 where date = l_date
   and name = l_name
   and code = l_code;
...
end;
```

I want to log this query into my own debug_table, but I don't want to just use a copied query (as in copy paste this as an insert to my debug_table). Is there a way to somehow log this query that was executed and insert it into my debug_table?

Comment: What do you want to be logged?
Please give more details.

Comment: The delete statement itself and the variables that were used. Is there a more efficient way than just writing an insert with the copy-pasted delete?

Comment: There is, maybe you should get familiar with Managing the Query Log in Oracle (if you have a BI SERVER): https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/biee/BIESG/GUID-7C4C8FA8-C417-4091-A8E8-B1ED35EBB391.htm#config_log_sys
If not, you need to log it by yourself.
You could create your own procedure that would actually run a dynamic sql, and store everything in debug_table.
I can imagine, it could be universal for every given query.
Or, you could create a trigger and access fields values from there, but only the fields values, not these that were used in WHERE clause.

Comment: What is the purpose to log a static query? It is already "logged" in the PL/SQL package definition. Just query `user_source` and get the query. Or write some additional procedure that will do this before execution and insert a call to this procedure right before your query (if you really want to log static text). But you may log variables' values to reproduce this query as it was executed.

Comment: What is the value of logging this ? It doesn't tell you how many rows were actually delete. I'd have a look at [this blog](https://connor-mcdonald.com/2020/08/04/level-up-your-audit-trigger-game/). It shows a method of auditing changes on a table - could be useful for your business case.